# Beckhoff TwinCat Scope CSV Format into pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, csv, twincat

After recording data in Beckhoff TwinCAT Scope, one can export this data to a CSV file. Said CSV file, however, has a rather complicated format. Can anyone suggestion the most effective way to import such a file into a pandas Dataframe so I can perform analysis?

An example of the format can be found here:
https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcscope2/html/TwinCATScopeView2_Tutorial_SaveExport.htm&id=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write a custom parser. Using the example data `scope_data.csv`:

```
Name,fasd,,,,
File,C;\,,,,
Start,dfsd,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
Name,Peak,Name,PULS1,Name,SINUS_FAST
Net id,123.123.123,Net id,123.123.124,Net Id,123.123.125
Port,801,Port,801,Port,801
,,,,,
0,0.6113936598,0,0.07994111349,0,0.08425652468
0,0.524852539,0,0.2051963401,0,0.4391185847
0,0.4993723482,0,0.2917317117,0,0.4583736263
0,0.5976553194,0,0.8675482865,0,0.8435987898
0,0.06087224998,0,0.7933980583,0,0.5614294705
0,0.1967968423,0,0.3923966599,0,0.1951608414
0,0.9723649064,0,0.5187276782,0,0.7646786192
```

You can import as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

scope_data = pd.read_csv(
    "scope_data.csv",
    skiprows=[*range(5), *range(6, 9)],
    usecols=[*range(1, 6, 2)]
)
```

Then you get

```
>>> scope_data.head()
       Peak     PULS1  SINUS_FAST
0  0.611394  0.079941    0.084257
1  0.524853  0.205196    0.439119
2  0.499372  0.291732    0.458374
3  0.597655  0.867548    0.843599
4  0.060872  0.793398    0.561429
```

I don't have the original scope csv, but a little adjustment of `skiprows` and `use_cols` should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

To read the bulk of the file (ignoring the header material) use the `skiprows` keyword argument to `read_csv`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows=18)
```

For the header material, I think you'd have to write a custom parser.