# Import Beckhoff twinCAT scope view csv format into Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, import, twincat

I try to import data from twinCAT into matlab for analyzing. 
I have tried it with the code:

Tb = readtable('LogTestScopeView1.csv');

But that didn't work. I guess the header of a twinCAT csv-file is a bit more complicated. 
Have someone experience with this?
Already many thanks.

Comment: Not sure about MATLAB, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58162557/6329629) are some answers for Python.

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on the header configuration you choose in the TwinCAT Scope Export Wizard. E.g. when choosing "Name only header" the `readtable()` command worked fine for me. Also, I selected "Comma" as CSV-Separator and "Point" as Decimal mark (see this
[Measurement Export Wizard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phw9M.png))

If you just need to quickly analyze the data and don't need code to automate this process, you can also use Matlab's import tool (`Home` -> `Import Data`), where you can interactively select the data to import.